# Google Play App Signing and Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, release, signing

I uploaded my signed apk using the new Google App Signing, and found out I need to change the authentication keys in order for the APIs to keep working.
The SHA1 is given directly on the google play console, so I used it successfully with for my Google APIs, however Facebook login key is different (28 characters ending by "=" ). 
Since I don't know the alias of the new keystore created by google, I don't know how to get this  key.
Hope someone can help.
Cheers,

Q

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just found out by myself. Actually for Facebook Login, you just need to translate the hexadecimal code of your SHA1 into Base64.
You can find some online tools to do it.
Hope this helps someone someday =)

Answer (score 14):

Thank me later

```
echo YOUR_HEXADECIMAL_KEY | xxd -r -p | openssl base64
```

Comment: Thank you later :)  For those using Windows, you have to download openssl from Google Code Archive and add it to your environment variables, then use the command with GitBach

Comment: Quick question: should it not be `echo -n YOUR_KEY`? Otherwise it encrypts the newlines that echo creates with your key

Comment: In fact, just tested both command, they produce the same output. Not sure what xxd does, but it probably strips that newline anyway

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another option, one can check the device's logcat & there's a Log from Facebook Sdk with the "key" expected/required to login, we can directly copy+paste from there as well instead of converting it through an online tool.